# node / edge : alternative to node.exe.config

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

The [documentation for Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) states that in order to have .net settings for my app, I need to put them in `node.exe.config`.

> How to: app.config
>
> When running C# code within Node.js app, the app config file is
>   node.exe.config and should be located right next to the node.exe file.

This will create conflicts as I have several edge applications running on this box. What are the alternatives?

Comment: `File.ReadAllText("myconfig.file")`? What have you tried?

Comment: The `app.config` is a .Net config file. I have to have it loaded and processed by the framework. Several settings in there are to configure .Net itself.

Comment: One alternative I have identified is to have one installation of node per application running on that box. But it's a Web server and it will have hundreds of edge application instances with their own configuration, so that does not scale very well.

Comment: Random suggestion: Does it work when the `node.exe.config` is next to your main JavaScript file?

Comment: Apparently, Edge.js does not support separate app.configs (yet). So I’d suggest you to create a feature request for this. There isn’t anything we can do over here about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put node.exe in each of your projects root directories. Then you can have `node.exe.config` for each project.

By the way, I am recommending to have node.exe for each project, because you have the ability to using different versions of NodeJS for each project without conflict. NodeJS updates very fast, and sometimes there are some changes that you want for one project, but may break the code of other project.